# Can an Ember Controller bind to changed events for it's own properties?

Tags: ember.js, property-binding, ember-observable

Given a controller like:

```
App.SignInController = Ember.Controller.extend
  authenticated: false
  authenticatedDidChange: (() =>
    console.log @get('authenticated')
  ).observes('controller.authenticated')
```

This doesn't seem to work so I must not understand how observers works. I *think* it is supposed to created an observer on controller.authenticated. However when I call `@set("authenticated", true)` nothing is logged.

Updated:
I did try replacing `controller.authenticated` with `App.signInController.authenticated` to no avail.

What am I missing?

Comment: The better solution is to use what @ryan suggests. Though, relying on `App.signInController.authenticated` could work, if you are sure that the object App.signInController has been instanciated.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I stumbled upon [an answer](http://www.quora.com/Ember-js/Can-I-observe-the-content-of-a-controller-with-addObserver) this Yehuda Katz on Quora.

```
App.friendsController = Ember.ArrayProxy.extend({
  contentDidChange: function() {
    // stuff here
  }.observes('content')
});
```

After reviewing this answer I noticed that the `observes` call only specifies the name of the property with no `controller` or `App.signInController` prefix. Changing my solution above to just `observes('authenticated')` works.

```
App.SignInController = Ember.Controller.extend
  authenticated: false
  authenticatedDidChange: (() ->
    console.log @get('authenticated')
  ).observes('authenticated')
```

Comment: Perfectly right, like computed properties, observers 'path' must be either relative to the current object, or absolute from a global namespace.